Is there a similar concept to 'utility' in information theory?
Recently began learning about information theory in earnest, and was tripped up for a while by the common heuristic definitions for information content. It seems to me like the concept of the information content of a message in the context of information theory is very tightly bound to the perspective from which the message is generated, and entirely unrelated to how the message is used.
For example, suppose there are two randomly chosen eight-bit numbers, one of which can be any of the 256 possibilities and the other of which is guaranteed to be either 4 or 231, and a message is sent out consisting of the two numbers randomly ordered in sequence. As I understand it, the information content of the messages would be either 10 bits (if the full-range random number happens not to be 4 or 231) or 9 bits (if the full-range number is either 4 or 231), with the excess bit of information being which of the two numbers happens to have been chosen first.
Now consider an observer of this message, who cares very much about whether the two numbers are exactly the same or not, but not about any other aspect of it. For a more concrete example, maybe the numbers are addresses that trucks are being sent to for deliveries, and if both trucks are being sent to the same address they need to issue orders for one truck to delay their arrival so they don't collide. Now from this observer's perspective, the 'information' described from the perspective of whatever system is sending out the message is almost completely meaningless- the only bit of information they care about is whether or not the two numbers are the same.
There are a number of vaguely paradoxical observations you can make about this situation depending on how you decide to interpret the various heuristic interpretations of 'information', such as noting that while messages that are more 'informative' are meant to be less likely to occur, you're far more likely to get a 10-bit message than a 9-bit message, or that for the observer the most informative messages of all are guaranteed to be some of those with the least information. Based on all of this, it seems to me like there should be some concept in information theory similar to the idea of utility in game theory, which describes the 'information content' of a message not in terms of some attempted 'objective' but useless measure of perspective, but in the context of a particular use case. Off-hand it seems to me like it would have utility (in the ordinary-language sense) in problems involving relaying messages and in potentially determining how messages could be most efficiently constructed. For example, in my above case, if no one but the described observer actually receives the messsage, there's no reason to send a 9/10 bit message containing both numbers rather than a 1-bit message simply saying whether or not they're the same. Is there such a concept? If so, what is it called? If not, why not?

Another fundamental topic of information theory is rate-distortion theory, which may be relevant.

The sort of problem you're describing can be captured by changing what it means to decode. Say the reconstruction is a single bit, $b$, and we impose a reconstruction loss of $\rho((x,y), b) =  \mathbf{1}\{ x = y, b = 0\} + \mathbf{1}\{x \neq y, b = 1\}).$ Then in the usual information theory setup, you can pick a blocklength, do some coding, and try to make the average loss small (in some sense). The framework is more than flexible enough to handle all this.
The trouble is that, as far as I know, there is no general theory of information transfer when one is concerned with arbitrary notions of reconstruction. In fact, the problem you described has flavour similar to both identification coding (a la Ahlswede and Dueck), and some forms of identity testing that are studied in the communication complexity literature, both of which are subfields in their own right (I'm also reminded of a nice paper by Orlitsky, which I've forgotten the name of unfortunately. I'll put it here if I remember). Often, simple capacity type quantities will yield some bounds on these, but there's no reason for them to be tight, and they often are not.
Naturally, the existence of these bodies of work also answer the question in your title affirmatively in that considerations of alternate problem structures do arise (quite often, actually). Just that there's no fully general theory. Note also that its atypical to have a general theory for any super-generic setup. E.g., even in the standard information theoretic setup, we don't really understand networked problems outside of a few special channels.

Thank you for the response, sorry for taking so long to respond (I've had sporadic internet access over the last week). I'm pretty sure I understand what you're getting at, will have to look at your recommendations!

There are many different processes and operations that are taking place in the example problem you present.

There is some process selecting a number uniformly from a set of 256 numbers. We can take the number selected from this process as a random number obtained by sampling a random variable we will denote as $X$. $X$ is uniformly distributed over the support set $\mathcal{X} = \{1,...,256\}$. The cardinality of the set $|\mathcal{X}|$ is $256$.

There is another process selecting a number uniformly from a set of two numbers. We can take the number selected from this process as a random number obtained by sampling a random variable we will denote as $Y$. $Y$ is uniformly distributed over the support set $\mathcal{Y} = \{4, 231\}$. The cardinality of the set $|\mathcal{Y}|$ is $2$.

There is some operation ($g$) which takes as input the samples from the two processes above and provides an array (or result) which is a concatenation of the two inputs as output. Another random variable $W$ determines the order of that concatenation. We can take $W$ and $Y$ to be iid variables in our case. We can take the output of the $g$ operation as being a sample obtained from sampling some random variable $Z$ (that is $Z = g(W, X, Y)$). The cardinality of the support set of $Z$, $|\mathcal{Z}|$, is some value less than $2 \cdot |\mathcal{X}||\mathcal{Y}|$.


Take the support set of $W$ as $\{0,1\}$ and let $\mathsf{z} = [\mathsf{x},\mathsf{y}]$ if $\mathsf{w} = 1$, and $\mathsf{z} = [\mathsf{y},\mathsf{x}]$ is $\mathsf{w} = 0$.

Define another random variable $E$ which models the other event of concern in your example which is when $\mathsf{x = y}$. Let $E = 1$ if $\mathsf{x = y}$, and $0$ otherwise.

With the above defined we can provide a cursory overview of the different observations outlined in the question.
If an observer is observing $X$ and $Y$ directly the entropy of the observed value is 9 bits (H(Y) = 1 bit from $Y$ and H(X) = $8$ bits from $X$ as you state) but if an observer is not observing $X$ and $Y$ directly but is instead observing $Z$ then the entropy of the observation less than $10$ bits in our case. The additional < 1 bit of entropy being a result of $W$. The entropy of $Z$ is a fixed value - it does not keep changing from being $9$ to $10$ bits.
If $\{\mathcal{X} \cap \mathcal{Y} \} = \{\mathcal{Y}\} = \{\mathcal{X}\}$ then $\mathsf{z}$ would have $10$ bits of entropy but if $\{\mathcal{X} \cap \mathcal{Y} \} = \emptyset$ then $Z$ would have $9$ bits of entropy. In any other case the entropy of $Z$ would evaluate to some value in between $9$ and $10$ bits (this is the case in our example - we have $\{\mathcal{X} \cap \mathcal{Y} \} = \{4, 231\}$ in our case).
Lastly, an observer who observes $Z$ with the sole purpose of estimating $E$ (the observer only cares about whether the two observations are equal) has his uncertainty reduce from $H(E)$ to $H(E | Z)$ bits of information by making observing $Z$. The difference between these two quantities is the mutual information between $E$ and $Z$ - denoted $I(E;Z)$.
Entropy tries to characterise how uncertain you are about some particular event and so it will naturally be dependent on what the event of concern is.
If you have an event with M equiprobable outcomes, M can be used to characterise how uncertain you are about the outcome. If we were to assign each outcome a unique sequence, with each sequence being made up of base-$B $ numbers, then we would on average need $\log_BM$ numbers for each sequence (at the very least). The entropy (in units of base $B$) or the amount of information we would need to resolve our uncertainty is thus then defined being as equal to $\log_BM$ units. If $B = 2$ the unit is bits.

Thank you for the answer! I think the answer above more directly addresses my general query, but this specific analysis of my example of course has a lot of value in its own right.
